Can $T$ and $Q$ be non-similar linear operators over $\mathbb K$, yet $\mathbb K[T]$ be isomorphic to $\mathbb K[Q]$?
Let $T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ be linear operators on $\mathbb K^4$. Then $T$ and $Q$ are not similar. Despite this, they have the same minimal polynomial $(x-1)^2$. I believe that, for a linear operator $L$, $\mathbb K[L]$ isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb K[x]}{(p)}$ where $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $L$. Therefore $\mathbb K[T] \cong \mathbb K[Q]$. Is this correct? It feels a bit odd that those algebras are isomorphic despite the linear operators not being similar.. If its true, is there an intuitive explanation for it?

As @SassatelliGiulio aptly comments: yes, the two rings are isomorphic, but the two modules are not. Perhaps we should not be surprised that the same (isomorphic) ring can have two not-isomorphic modules. For me, that gives a conceptual explanation/relief to a perhaps-seemingly paradoxical "elementary" linear algebra conundrum. :)

Right, i'm accustomed in viewing a linear operator $L$ as equivalent to a $\mathbb K[x]$-module rather than a $\mathbb K[L]$-module.

@Carla_, yes, good. And, for current mathematics, probably less ambiguous to say "isomorphic" rather than "equivalent", although, of course, the latter is what we mean, colloquially. :)  Some of the very-classical matrix-algebra terminology (e.g., "similar") is somehow archaic. "Conjugate" might be clearer, these days. :)

That's funny, my first instinct was to say "isomorphic" rather than "similar" but i was worried that the former would be less clearer to others than the latter.

Oh, did you mean i should have said "isomorphic" in my comment to this answer instead of "equivalent"? I didn't say isomorphic because linear operators are not in the same category as $\mathbb K[x]$-modules, altho there is an equivalence of (sub)categories

@Carla_, oh, yeah, it depends how you set things up! E.g., if we convert $k[T]$ modules to $k[x]$ modules in the natural way (obvious functor...), then everything is a $k[x]$ module. But, sure, that's just grouping things differently.

To be a bit more explicit, i usually think of linear operators on a vector space $V$ as elements of the category of functors from the free monoid on 1 generator into the endomorphism category of $V$. But yeah for vector spaces it should also be equivalent to some category of modules.

@Carla_ Ah! Very reasonable! But, still, in my own experience, I have found that, sometimes, the top-heaviness of abstraction out-weighs the purported efficiency of understanding. But/and, indeed, one's prior experience can lead to wildly varying appraisals of "(top-) heaviness"... :)

@Carla_ ... reflecting a bit further: in my mathematical youth, "equivalence of categories" was not a widely known thing. Even the idea that "similarity of matrices" was really about an isomorphism (rather than a formulaic thing), was (in English, in the U.S.) a novelty! :)
